# Issue setting up grid style results

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to show a table in a grid result table and I am failing...

I want it to look like so:

[image]

I'm trying to do it this way, but it only shows one line:

```
<div class="resultsTable">
            <table style="display: inline-table">
                <tr ng-repeat="result in results" class="resultsBox">
                    <td>
                        <img src="{{result.imageUrl}}" width="200px">
                        <h4>{{result.name}}</h4>
                    </td>
                </tr>



            </table>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.resultsBox{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.resultsBox>img{
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.resultsTable{
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: inline-table;
    height: 500px;

}
```

Comment: `img` is not a child of `.resultsBox`. And it's not HTML code but server-side code or template before being compiled to HTML code. Please show what the browser will see.

Comment: Thanks. Im new to web development. Im using angularjs, the html is rendered from the client server which is what you see here. Ng-repeat is making copies of this table row. The issue here is styling I believe, since Im seeing a line of results but they are stacked in 1 column as opposed to 2. This is all the html it takes to display n number of items

Comment: This isn't HTML code that a browser can display without first compiling it with JavaScript. This is AngularJS template looking a lot like HTML but many loops and variables will be expanded (in JS) to create what the browser will finally render with real `src` and real number of tables, rows and cells. Look with Firebug or Inspect how many cells and rows you've. I bet you've 1 cell per row thus 1 column and not 2 columns as you'd like. This sort of framework (and CSS preprocessors) aren't for beginners if you don't exaclty know what happens IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the template you have shared it's normal that you see only one column of **n** row. It is not link to the css but to the markup that will be generated.

Your `results` property is an array of one dimension something like [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}] but you want to display a matrix an array of two dimensions i.e [[{obj1}, {obj2}], [{obj3}, {obj4}]]. Unfortunately it is not that easy in AngularJS to generate a matrix based on a one dimension array. That's why I will recommend that you change the structure of your result to match its matrix display. Then change your template to something like :

```
<div class="resultsTable">
    <table style="display: inline-table">
      <tr ng-repeat="row in results"> //loop over all row of 2 elements
        <td ng-repeat="cell in row" class="resultsBox"> //loop over elements
          <img src="{{cell.imageUrl}}" width="200px">
          <h4>{{cell.name}}</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

See a working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mJYpIVtznXaB441V8o2h?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's overkill. This simply needs to use a flow layout that allows to items per line before going to the next line. I guess I should have just asked about a flow layout